# Numpy random seed valid for entire jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm using functions from `numpy.random` on a Jupyter Lab notebook and I'm trying to set the seed using `numpy.random.seed(333)`. This works as expected only when the seed setting is in the same notebook cell as the code. For example, if I have a script like this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(44)

ll = [3.2,77,4535,123,4]

print(np.random.choice(ll))
print(np.random.choice(ll))
```

The output from both `np.random.choice(ll)` will be same, because the seed is set:

```
# python seed.py
4.0 
123.0
# python seed.py
4.0
123.0
```

Now, if I try to do the same on the Jupyter notebook, I get different results:

```
# in [11]
import numpy as np
# even if I set the seed here the other cells don't see it
np.random.seed(333)

# in [12]
np.random.choice([1,23,44,3,2])
23
# gets the same numbers

# in [13]
np.random.choice([1,23,44,3,2])
44
# gets different numbers every time I run this cell again
```

Is there a way to set the numpy random seed globally in a Jupyter lab notebook?

Comment: But you're repeatedly calling `randint` so it's going to give you a different number in a subsequent cell, you'd have to set the seed prior to calling randint to get consistency this is no different to if you were in the python terminal and did the same subsequent calls

Comment: Changed the code to reflect what I mean.

Comment: You still don't seem to understand, once you've called `seed` and then you repeatedly call `choice` you are going to get a different value unless you reset the seed, I'm not sure why this is unclear

Comment: If you're asking if it's possible to get the same result without setting the seed explicitly I don't think this is possible

Comment: I believe OP is saying if you run the seed cell and then immediately call choice() in another cell you get some value X but _even after you re-run the seed cell_ re-running the choice() cell gives a different value Y.

Answer (score 13):

Because you're repeatedly calling randint, it generates different numbers each time. It's important to note that seed does not make the function consistently return the same number, but rather makes it such that the same **sequence** of numbers will be produced if you repeatedly run randint the same amount of times. Therefore, you're getting the same **sequence** of numbers every time you re-run the random.randint, rather than it always producing the same number.

Re-seeding in that specific cell, before each random.randint call, should work, if you want the same random number every single time. Otherwise, you can expect to consistently get the same sequence of numbers, but not to get the same number every time.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the code to reflect what I mean with "getting the same value".

Comment: My answer still stands. Rerunning the program reseeded the random generator. Reseeding your Jupyter notebook should allow you to reproduce the same results. Try getting two choices, rerunning the first cell, then generating the choices again. You should get the same ones.

Comment: That's what I have been doing: reseeding with the same seed on each notebook cell, but it doesn´ t look like a good solution.

Comment: @Ivan Unfortunately, I believe that's what you have to do. Alternatively, you could put the seed statement in the cell that you're trying to work with so that it reseeds every time you want to run it. Just remember - seeding will generate the same sequence of stuff as you rerun cells, but it does not mean that your outputs will always be the same unless you keep reseeding.

Answer (score 4):

Because you run `np.random.choice()` in the cells different from `np.random.seed()`. Try to run `np.random.seed()` and `np.random.choice()` in the same cell, you'll get same number.

```
# in [11]
import numpy as np
# even if I set the seed here the other cells don't see it
np.random.seed(333)
np.random.choice([1,23,44,3,2])
2
# gets the same numbers

# in [12]
import numpy as np
# even if I set the seed here the other cells don't see it
np.random.seed(333)
np.random.choice([1,23,44,3,2])
2
# gets the same numbers
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking on how to work around.

Comment: Is it the accepted answer then? Or did you mean this is exactly what you'd like to avoid?

Comment: I believe that the explanation is wrong. It doesn't really matter if it is in the same cell or not but as explained in the accepted answer, the number of how many times it's called matters. If you want to check it, just put 
`import numpy as np

np.random.seed(223)
print(np.random.choice([1,23,44,3,2]))
print(np.random.choice([1,23,44,3,2]))`
into one cell... Also see the comments from @Ed Chum and @Sam Carpenter

Comment: @Mywork, yah, but his question is "Is there a way to set the numpy random seed globally...?" The answer is no, you need to call `np.random.seed(333)` every time you want to generate the same sequence. So the workaround is to call `np.random.seed(333)` in the same cell you print random numbers.

Comment: @allenyllee so answer that. And as I said, the answer should be "no, you need to do it before every call if you want the same number regardless of the cell you're in" and then your example. Your answer/wording is misleading... It suggests that the problem is with jupyter cells (similarly like the question is misleading) but that is not the case.