# How to set random seed for pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()?

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: I figured out that the issue was related to Jupyter notebooks. I can't set the seed globally and get the same result on every run. I have to set the random seed in the code cell with `pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()`.

Original question:
I'm trying to set the random state so I can get reproducible results for the DataFrames made with pandas's `pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()`.

I've set the random seed for Python and NumPy. Is there another random seed I can set to get reproducible results?

```
seed = 34

# python
import random
random.seed(seed)

# numpy
np.random.seed(seed)
```

I've searched SO to no avail.

Comment: I'm not sure if you could do that. This line (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/util/testing.py#L1811) in the source code shows that the dataframe is created from a random numpy matrix within the scope of ``testing.py``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was related to Jupyter notebooks. I can't set the seed for the notebook globally and get the same result on every run. I have to set the random seed in the code cell with `pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()`.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51425032/4590385) helped confirm.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use panda's testing framework with random seeds, try this:

```
from numpy import random, prod, str_
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas.util.testing as test
from pandas import DataFrame, Series


def rand_df(N=30, K=4, seed=0, nchars=10):

    random.seed(seed)
    index = (
        random.choice(test.RANDS_CHARS, size=nchars * prod(N))
        .view((str_, nchars))
        .reshape(N)
    ).astype('O')

    return DataFrame({c: Series(randn(N), index=index) for c in test.getCols(K)})


a = rand_df()
b = rand_df()
print(a == b)
```